# Foundry Slate - Table widget get cell value

Tags: palantir-foundry, slate

In Slate I have a table widget and like to read out values from cells by clicking the cell. I heard it might work using 'ClickEvent' but I have no clude how to do this :-(

Anyone has experience?

I tried nothing becuase I don't know how.
I like to read out a cell to use as a filter to filter the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for custom ClickEvent handlers for Table and HTML widgets and how to pass values into Events through these clicks in the [Slate Best Practices](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/best-practices-app-functionality/#custom-event-triggers) docs.

You can also look in the Slate reference examples on your Foundry instance and find some interactive apps to work from.

`/Foundry Training and Resources/Reference Examples/Application Development in Slate/1. Tutorials/2. Tutorial - Intro to Slate Hidden Features` has an example at the very bottom of a table with buttons embedded in each row that works using the custom ClickEvent framework.

There are lots of other reference examples for all kinds of Slate implementation patterns in these folders that might be relevant to explore.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. They help a lot :-)